# Laravel 5 InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [.admin] not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is **student.php** and my function for admin:

```
 public function admin(Request $request){

       if($request->isMethod('get')){
       return \View::make('/admin');
    }
       else
        {

                 $UserData['email'] = Input::get('username');
                 $UserData['password'] = Input::get('password');
                 User::create($UserData);
                 return 'admintest';
                 //return Redirect::to('/view');
         }
   }
```

**routes.php**

```
      Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin', 'student@admin');
```

This is admin form:

```
     {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/admin')) !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


    User Name:<br />
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

     <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />


  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Don't know why showing error:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [.] not found

Comment: What is the name of the file, that has admin form ? Give the full name

Comment: which view are talking about.. i didnt get u

Comment: You want to return the admin form. Isn't it ?

Comment: as i just go to open the admin form.. it shows me this error.

Comment: Yes, What is the name of the file that has the admin form ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A view should an extension `.blade.php`.

So your file that has the admin form should have the name `admin.blade.php`

**Note :**

If you have the view under any sub directory like `somefolder/admin.blade.php`

Then you should do like this

`return \View::make('somefolder/admin');`

Learn more about [templating](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) here :)

Answer (score 33):

If you recently deployed you project to your production server or moved the project to another server, do not forget to **clear the app cache** by running these commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

it should fix it.

Also consider updating your `.env` file to match new environment variables.

Comment: Can you give more detail about updating .env file for environment variable? btw, clearing the app cache worked, thanks!

Comment: When deploying a laravel app from dev environement to production environement you should update **constants in .env file at the root of the project**. For ex. `APP_URL=http://localhost` in dev should be `APP_URL=https://domain.tld` in production environment. you should always exclude the file when pushing to another environment. and after each edit of the .env file you also need to run `php artisan config:cache` or laravel will not recognize new constants.

Answer (score 20):

If any of the answers above do not work. why don't you try modifying the name of **config.php** project/bootstrap/cache/config.php to another name like config.php.old  it worked for me with laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because I had a backslash `\`, the solution was change it to slash:

```
return \View::make('folder/admin');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to reference your views beginning with a slash.

This:

`return \View::make('/admin');`

Should look like:

`return \View::make('admin');`

Answer (score 0):

Please check first that  folder is under views folder
i.e `resources/views/foldername/filename`

then you can test

```
Route::get('route_name', function () {
    return view('foldername.file_name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an authentication skeleton generator which might have been previously used prior to your current state in your project. I had this error and I was coming from a git clone that had Laravel extra's omitted from sharing good practices.

By reissuing the command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#introduction

Answer (score 0):

I just remove '.blade.php' at the end of the path.